# Нахождение наименьшего вершинного покрытия в дереве

Tags: алгоритм, графы

В одной стране под названием Инфолэнд есть n городов, связанных между собой двусторонними дорогами. Цепью между городами a и b называется маршрут между этими городами, который использует каждую дорогу не более одного раза. Дороги в этой стране построены так, что для любых городов a и b существует ровно одна цепь, связывающая эти два города. Правительство этой страны приняло указ о контроле дорог своего государства. Было решено в некоторых городах создать комитеты по контролю всех дорог, начинающихся или заканчивающихся в этом городе. В целях экономии необходимо создать наименьшее возможное число таких комитетов, но чтобы любая дорога находилась под контролем хотя бы одного комитета.
В ответ вывести минимальное число городов.

Мой алгоритм. Из условия очевидно,что данные города образуют граф,при этом этот граф будет деревом,тогда,чтобы найти минимальное количество городов необходимо найти его наименьшее вершинное покрытие. Вот тут и начинается проблема. Поиск наименьшего вершинного покрытия-это NP-полная задача. Но если бы это был двудольный граф,то задача сведётся к поиску максимального паросочетания. Вопрос: как мне свести мой граф  к двудольному и вообще возможно ли такое? Можно ли считать мой алгоритм корректным? И если нет,то как тогда решить данную задачу
Привожу код на С++,вылетает на большей части тестов,как исправить или написать лучше?

```
   #include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<queue>
#include<iomanip>
#include <set> 
#pragma comment(linker, "/STACK:1677721600")
using namespace std;
int n;
vector <vector<int>> G1(n);
vector<vector<int>>K1(n);
vector<int>I(n);

int get_independent_set(int u)
{
    if (I[u] != 0)
        return I[u];
    else
    {
        int children_sum = 0;
        int grandchildren_sum = 0;
            // цикл по всем детям
        for (int i = 0; i < G1[u].size(); i++)
            children_sum = children_sum + get_independent_set(G1[u][i]);
                // цикл по всем внукам
        for (int i = 0; i < K1[u].size(); i++)
            grandchildren_sum = grandchildren_sum + get_independent_set(K1[u][i]);
                    // запоминаем, чтобы не пересчитывать ещё раз
        I[u] = max(1 + grandchildren_sum, children_sum);
        return I[u];
    }
}

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    ofstream fout("output.txt");

    fin >> n;


    vector <vector<int>> G(n);
    vector<int>I1(n);
    int i, v, k = 0;

    while (fin >> i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            fin >> v;
            G[k].push_back(v-1);
        }
        k++;
    }
    vector<bool>used(n);
    queue<int>q1;
    queue<int> q;
    q.push(0);
    vector<vector<int>>child(n);
    vector<vector<int>>vnuki(n);
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        int m = q.front();
        q.pop();
        used[m] = true;

        for (int j = 0; j < G[m].size(); j++)
        {
            if (!(used[G[m][j]]))
            {
                child[m].push_back(G[m][j]);
                q.push(G[m][j]);
                for (int k = 0; k < G[G[m][j]].size(); k++)
                {
                    if (G[G[m][j]][k] != m)
                        vnuki[m].push_back(G[G[m][j]][k]);
                }
            }


        }

    }
    G1 = child;
    K1 = vnuki;
    I = I1;

    int ver = get_independent_set(0);
    fout << n - ver;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дополнением к вершинному покрытию является множество независимых вершин, а задача о независимом множестве **для дерева** решается динамическим программированием.

Последний алгоритм в [wiki описан](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5#%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%B2_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5)

Мощность множества (либо мы берём корень и внуков, либо всех детей, иначе какое-то ребро будет упущено)

```
I(root) = max (1 + Sum{I(внуков)}, Sum{I(детей)})
```

Сами множества можно получать и записывать при выборе максимума

Comment: То есть мощность независимого множества совпадёт с мощностью вершинного покрытия?

Comment: Нет, их сумма равна количеству вершин дерева.  "Дополнение" означает, что каждая вершина входит или в ВП, или в НМ

Comment: Ага,точно,я чуть запутался просто. Эти множества не будут пересекаться просто. Сори за такой глупый вопрос. Попробую реализовать

Comment: если I(u) уже посчитано, то возвратить I(u),вот такое встретилось в псевдокоде. Как я узнаю,что I(u) уже посчитано?

Comment: Динамическое программирование с запоминанием посчитанных результатов- мемоизация. Например, просчитали вариант для некого узла- сложили в массив или в мап. Снова потребовался результат для него - посмотрели - если есть в массиве - просто взяли оттуда, не пересчитывая заново.

Comment: А как мне узнать кто у данной вершины внуки?

Comment: Так дети детей - в цикле по детям сразу и внуков посчитать

Comment: А вот от индусов код именно для покрытия https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vertex-cover-problem-set-2-dynamic-programming-solution-tree/

Comment: Главный вопрос. данные задачи заданы следующим образом:В первой строке находится одно целое число n (1 ≤ n ≤ 100 000). Далее идут n строк, описывающих для каждого города все города, соединённые прямой дорогой с этим городом: сначала число ki таких городов, затем номера этих городов. Так вот как мне представить эти данные в виде дерева?

Comment: Это списки смежности. Если сложность в том, кто корень  -любой узел сойдёт за начало для обхода в ширину.

Comment: Добавляю свой код. Вылетает вновь на половине тестов

Comment: Всё сработало))Спасибо всем)

Comment: Отлично, что добили задачку!

Answer (score 2):

Дерево является ациклическим графом. Любой ациклический граф является двудольным. Задача нахождения минимального вершинного покрытия в двудольном графе легко и эффективно решается через задачу о максимальном паросочетании в двудольном графе (см. [Теорему Кёнига](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%9A%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0))).

Максимальное паросочетание в двудольном графе строит [алгоритм Хопкрофта-Карпа](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%B0) (или, альтернативно, Форда-Фалкерсона).

И это еще если просто считать дерево двудольным графом. Но именно в дереве задача может решаться еще проще. Навскидку: а просто жадный набор вершин максимальной "непокрытой" степени тут не подойдет?

Comment: добавил код на с++